# React Router: Update only one query parameter instead of replacing all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

I am trying to update only one query param key-value on button click using react-router (v5).

```
const btnClickHandler = () =>{
    history.push({ search: 'popup=false' });
}
```

I want this code to update the url from:

```
https://base-url.com/?popup=true&checked=true
```

to:

```
https://base-url.com/?popup=false&checked=true
```

but instead, it replaces the whole search to:

```
https://base-url.com/?popup=false
```

Basically, instead of replacing all the query param key value, how can I replace only one?

Comment: just in my mind, you can create a helper component that recieved obj with bool value and recreate all path by the existed url include your changing.

Answer (score 16):

With the version 6 of react-router-dom, you could:

```
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    let updatedSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());
    updatedSearchParams.set('operation', 'edit');
    setSearchParams(updatedSearchParams.toString());
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to merge the query params yourself before updating them. You could use `query-string` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) library to make your job easier.

```
import qs from 'query-string';

const Component = ({ location}) => {

    const btnClickHandler = () =>{
        const queryParams = qs.parse(location.search);
        const newQueries = { ...queryParams, popup:false};
        history.push({ search: qa.stringify(newQueries) });
    }

 }
```